# Catia V6 - Escaping out user selection box causes error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, catia

I am developing an application in C#, part of which requires an interactive user selection using the inbuilt function:

```
SelectMultipleElements( CATSafeArrayVariant  iFilterType, 
 CATBSTR  iMessage, 
 boolean  iMaySkipInteractiveSelection, 
 CATMultiSelectionMode  iMultiSelectionMode, 
 boolean  iTooltip) As CATBSTR
```

This presents a window in the Catia session -that I lack the rep to add a picture of...

Which is all fine and dandy if the user can find the correct geometry on-screen.

If they press the escape key which this UI is active, it rightly disappears.

But, if the script is restarted (after an Escape press), I get a COM exception whenever this interactive selection window is requested again:

`The script is badly written.
Since the beginning of the script execution, the user pressed the Escape key, and the script did not exit. See Selection.SelectElement documentation`

Which prevents the window from re-displaying.
The only way that i've found to make the problem go away is to restart the Catia session - fine for me during debug/testing, but not a viable solution for our designers, who won't want to have to reload what they're working on.

Dassaults Automation documentation is quite frankly shocking, and I've had no joy finding a solution in there.

How can I have avoid this error when escape is pressed? I'm hoping it's not a Catia-specific issue, but I'm relatively new to creating standalone apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, eventually and after investigating with colleagues, this is a massive bug in the Catia application.

We found no way to prevent this problem, other than finding a workaround that does not rely on the "SelectMultipleElements" function